# WPF and Caliburn Not Binding Nested UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, caliburn.micro

I'm simply trying to create a binding for a UserControl within a UserControl using WPF/Caliburn, but I am having trouble properly binding the nested UserControl.

The basic layout is a ShellViewModel : Conductor, and within the ShellView there is a ContentControl that is populated by the ShellViewModel.ActivateItem method that loads a UserControl (PageViewModel), and within the PageView UserControl there is a nested UserControl called "SimpleControl".

The binding works when the page loads (it displays the "Initial Text Value" string in the nested UserControl), but it does not appear to be bound to the PropertyChanged event on PageView (and never updates its value when the test button is pressed). The Label in the Parent UserControl (PageView) is bound correctly/updates as expected.

PageView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CaliburnTest.Views.PageView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CaliburnTest.Views"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel Background="Aqua">
        <Label Content="{Binding TextLabelTest, FallbackValue=DEFAULT}"></Label>
        <local:SimpleControl cal:Bind.Model="WPFCaliburnTemplate.Views.PageView" TextValue="{Binding TextLabelTest}"></local:SimpleControl>
        <Button Name="UpdateTextButton">Update Text</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

PageViewModel.cs:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace CaliburnTest.ViewModels
{
    public class PageViewModel : Screen
    {
        private string _textLabelTest;
        public string TextLabelTest
        {
            get { return _textLabelTest; }
            set
            {
                _textLabelTest = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TextLabelTest);
            }
        }

        public PageViewModel()
        {
            TextLabelTest = "Initial Text Value";
        }

        public void UpdateTextButton()
        {
            TextLabelTest = "Updated Text Value";
        }
    }
}
```

SimpleControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CaliburnTest.Views.SimpleControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro.Platform.Core"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Border Margin="10" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF9A9A9A">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Name="TextLabel"></Label>
        </StackPanel>        
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

And finally SimpleControl.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace CaliburnTest.Views
{
    public partial class SimpleControl : UserControl
    {
        public SimpleControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static DependencyProperty TextValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextValue", typeof(string), typeof(SimpleControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", TextValueChangedCallBack));
        public string TextValue
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextValueProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TextValueProperty, value);
                Refresh();
            }
        }

        protected static void TextValueChangedCallBack(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as SimpleControl).TextValue = (string)e.NewValue;
        }

        private void Refresh()
        {
            TextLabel.Content = TextValue;
        }
    }
}
```

I have been banging on this all day and cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've tried all combinations of different DataContexts, RelativeSources, and whatever else I can find on SO and Google but am still coming up short. I have a much more complicated custom UserControl I'm trying to work with but I created this simple example to try and figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with all sorts of combinations and I believe I found a result that appears to work, though I'm not entirely sure why:

First, I changed the way I was binding the "TextValue" dependency property to:

```
    <local:SimpleControl TextValue="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.TextLabelTest}" />
```

However, this was still only working for the initial value and the binding was not updating when the string was updated. In the end, I had to edit SimpleControl.xaml.cs like so:

```
    protected static void TextValueChangedCallBack(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // (sender as SimpleControl).TextValue = (string)e.NewValue;
        (sender as SimpleControl).Refresh();
    }
```

As you can see, I commented out the line setting the SimpleControl.TextValue (and in turn setting the TextValueProperty DependencyProperty) and simply called the SimpleControl.Refresh() method to update the label. I'm not sure why setting the TextValueProperty was breaking the DependencyProperty (even though it was already set when the string updated), but I think I need to go brush up on some MSDN articles!